# It was very different, when the masters of the science sought immortality and power

Tags: pronouns

The following extract is from Frankenstein by Mary Shelley. I'd like to know what the "it" and "such views" refer to. Does the "it" refer to modern natural philosophy, or the circumstances in general? Does "such views" refer to the view that modern natural philosophy was not contemptible when scientists were seeking immortality?

> Besides, I had a contempt for the uses of modern natural philosophy. **It** was very different, when the masters of the science sought immortality and power; **such views**, although futile, were grand: but now the scene was changed. The ambition of the enquirer seemed to limit itself to the annihilation of those visions on which my interest in science was chiefly founded. I was required to exchange chimeras of boundless grandeur for realities of little worth.

Answer (score 1):

> It was very different, when the masters of the science sought immortality and power;

This is a cleft structure, or at least it can be interpreted that way.   The "it" refers to the following subordinate clause.   When the masters of that science sought immortality and power is the thing that was very different.

The sentence as a whole still has the same meaning if you read it as a generic "it", referring to circumstances in general.   It also works if you take "it" to mean natural philosophy, but not in its modern condition.

It might be helpful to know that "natural philosophy" is a synonym for what we now call the physical sciences -- physics, chemistry and biology.

> such views, although futile, were grand: but now the scene was changed.

Here, "views" means something less like an opinion and more like a goal.   "Such views" refers back to *seeking immortality and power*.

Comment: Do you find Mary Shelley's writing style exemplary by contemporary standards?

Answer (score 0):

"It" refers to the time when the "masters of sciences" had grand views, as opposed to the different and current times, when inquirers were bent on annihilating such views.